# c# lambda get list of task between two dates

Tags: c#

my brain is boiling right now.

I have a list of tasks where i am programming a search filter for, the users should be able to filter the result with dates, let's say that i create a task that can be picked up between 03-03-2018 and 23-03-2018, my problems is now the lambda expressions, i will try to explain it bette:

in my Task model i have 4 different datetime objects that i work with,

- AvailableDate: Pickup date start
- PickupDate: Pickup date end
- RequestDate: Delivery date start
- DeliveryDateTo: Delivery date end

my problems is that if the user choose to filter the search result like this:

The user picks the dates with a datepicker, let's say that the user wants to view all results that's is avalible for pickup between the 01-03-2018 and 14-03-2018

the task that is created should be visible because the user choose a date range where one of the dates is in between the pickup range, but it's not working like it should, i will post my code now:

```
string TempPickupDateFrom = PickupDateFrom.ToString();
string TempPickupDateTo = PickupDateTo.ToString();
DateTime TempNewPickupDateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(TempPickupDateFrom, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime TempNewPickupDateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(TempPickupDateTo, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string ConvertNewPickupDateFrom = TempNewPickupDateFrom.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime NewPickupDateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(ConvertNewPickupDateFrom, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string ConvertNewPickupDateTo = TempNewPickupDateTo.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime NewPickupDateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(ConvertNewPickupDateTo, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
tasks = tasks.Where(m => m.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= NewPickupDateFrom || m.PickUpDate.GetValueOrDefault() >= NewPickupDateTo).ToList();
```

Hopes this makes any sense to someone, i am getting nuts about it...

Comment: I might be wrong but ... shouldn't the condition be:

m => m.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() >= NewPickupDateFrom && m.PickUpDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= NewPickupDateTo

Just a thought ...

Comment: Why are you doing all that converting back and forth between dates and strings?

Comment: @RufusL because when i get the date it's MM-dd-yyyy and i need dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: What type of object are you comparing it with? I assumed it was a nullable DateTime?

Comment: The MM-dd-yyyy stuff is only for formatting, it doesn't affect the underlying `DateTime` object, so you'd only need to do that if you were storing your dates as strings. Which hopefully is not the case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Let's say that the user wants to view all results that's is available for pickup between the 01-03-2018 and 14-03-2018"

From your comment below, it sounds like you want to select all the tasks where either the AvailableDate or the PickupDate are between the PickupDateFrom (`01-03-2018`) the PickupDateTo (`14-03-2018`):

```
var availableTasks = tasks.Where(task => 
    (task.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() >= PickupDateFrom && 
    task.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= PickupDateTo) || 
    (task.PickupDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= PickupDateFrom &&
    task.PickupDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= PickupDateTo).ToList();
```

Comment: that would not work, because let's say that i want to see all tasks that can be picked up between 03-03-2018 and 23-03-2018 and a task is created where the pickup date is between the 03-03-2018 and 28-03-2018 i would not see them, i need to see the tasks as long as one of the values is in the range between the two dates.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question...I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using your time guys, but i fould my solution, after a lot more headache:

```
tasks = tasks.Where(m => m.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() >= NewPickupDateFrom && m.PickUpDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= NewPickupDateTo || m.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= NewPickupDateFrom && m.PickUpDate.GetValueOrDefault() >= NewPickupDateTo || m.AvailableDate.GetValueOrDefault() <= NewPickupDateTo && m.PickUpDate.GetValueOrDefault() >= NewPickupDateFrom).ToList();
```